# GA Event Tracking Not Working

Tags: php, html, google-analytics, analytics, event-tracking

Can anyone see a problem with the code here for tracking this button?
Fixed it from the previous post and still nothing with the new code:

```
<form id="constant-contact-signup2" action="http://www.truckingoffice.com/trucking-software-blog" method="post">
<div class="kws_input_fields">
<div class='cc_email_address kws_input_container'>
<label for='cc_email_address' class=''> Sign up for our Trucking Office Newsletter <span class="req" title="The  Sign up for our Trucking Office Newsletter  field is required">*</span></label>
<input type='text' value='' size="30"  placeholder='john.appleseed@apple.com' name='fields[email_address][value]' class='t  required' id='cc_email_address' />
<input type="hidden" name="fields[email_address][label]" value=" Sign up for our Trucking Office Newsletter " />
<input type="hidden" name="fields[email_address][req]" value="1" /></div>

<input type="submit" style='position:absolute; width:0;height:0;visibility:hidden!important;' name='constant-contact-signup-submit' onclick=”_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Button', 'Click']);” />
```

Privacy by SafeSubscribe

Been working on this one all week and still nothing. Any al all help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is `”` in your `onclick`? Why don't you use `"` instead?

Comment: That was from some code I copied over; I changed it, I'll see what happens in a day because of the delay in event tracking

Comment: You can also use the error console in your browser to see if an issue with how you have it set up.

Comment: i'm not picking up any errors on the page within the error console, just gave it a run through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_trackEvent` and `_trackPageview` work by making a tracking pixel request to the Google servers -- you could be running into a timing problem where the image request is canceled because of a request for rendering a new page. A common solution is to delay the form submission a small amount after the tracking call.

Using jQuery, something like:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('#constant-contact-signup2 input[type=submit]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Button', 'Click']);
    setTimeout(function(){$('#constant-contact-signup2').submit()}, 150);
  });
})
```

Comment: where would I add this code within WP? since I don't really have access to a header like in a regular html doc

Comment: I'd either put it at the end of the page (before the closing body tag), or right after the form. Just enclose it in `script` tags.